# Change order whilst keeping ID field unchanged

Tags: vb.net, sorting

i am struggling to find a solution for following. It is hard to find a title for it by the way :)

I am making a tool where i want to track subscriptions to an event. For managing that I have a table with x (25+) number of positions to be filled.
This tool is in VB.net with an underlying MSSQL Database

That Position will be assigend with a 'userid' and some attributes as 'getradio1' , 'getsradio2' etc.

All of that is easy. So you will get something like this in the 'position' table.

[image: Table before]

Now it comes - and the questions is twofold : Can it be done and if yes how ?

Every UserID has a kind of priority ranking (in the UserID Database)

Now what i want to is to have the position filled in by order of that ranking . Lets assume that the ranking is as follows

- UserID101 = Ranking 14
- UserID103 = Ranking 5
- UserID106 = Ranking 11
- UserID102 = Ranking 39
- UserID118 = Ranking 1
- UserID114 = Ranking 6

Then i want the table updated so that the position is 'reassigned' according to rank as follows (also including the 'getradio' colums
[image: result after sorting]

Ideally would be that if a new PositionID was assigned it would automatically do the 'reordering'.

I tried to descridbe the problem as simple and complete as possible. But if you have more question donot hesitate.

Thanks already for your help

Comment: Is it safe to assume you are using Excel for this? Excel doesn't really have "tables" - It has ListObjects, but not Tables. Or are you calling a worksheet a "table"?

Comment: Thansk for the question. I clarified it in the question. The example i made up (and sorted) in Excel for making it clear what it is i want to achieve.

Comment: *"This tool is in VBA.net"*. Given that there is no such thing, that seems unlikely.

Comment: That must VB.net of course:) Guess one knows what i mean

Comment: I’m a little lost on what you’re asking.  Is it query the data and order it by rank for display, or is it update the position name in the database based on the value of the rank?  Or is it completely rewrite the data table in your pre-defined order?

Comment: Hi, as you can notice in the example to idea is that position and the other fields are replaced in the order of the rank. The idea is that persons get a numbered bib and that they are in order of ranking (experience) so they can be easily recognised by the physical number they are wearing.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really answer the question of what exactly you are trying to do.  If this is simply ordering the records when you retrieve them from the DB, that is as simple as using the Order By clause on your query.  If that is the case, you need to update your question with your Data retrieval/Query method(s).  Or is this something deeper?

Comment: When you put the two examples next to eachother you will see that in the second the colums UserID, Getsradio1 en getsradio 2 are in the order of ranking - whilst the culums positionname/position ID stays the same. I just want userid to be reassigned to Position using the ranking order. In Excel that takes one second (select the fields you want to reorder and then choose the column). I cannot give you any example of code as i have no clue how to deal with this. I do know how to order using SQL but then it always reorders the whole row . I just want a part of the selected rows to 'reorder' .

Comment: Yeah, still struggling to understand what your goal is here.  Are you meaning you want to execute some update statements on you database table to rewrite the records in your order?  Have you loaded these records into any sort of collection, if so update the question with details of how

Comment: Hi, That indeed should be the goal - meaning replace some colums in the record with 'my order'. I have not done anything as i have no idea how to do it. That was the question :) . If you put the two examples next to eacht other you will see that ID 101 is moved from Position 1 to Position 6 since he has the lowest ranking. ID 103 stays in Position 2 since he has second ranking. Assume that id101 would have another (higher) ranking then ID103 would move to Poistion1 etc etc

Comment: Ok, so taken a while to get there, but here we are.  Getting back to previous comments, any real answers on how to sort this data and update the db is going to some degree on exactly how you've loaded this data and how you've got it stored in memory (class collection, or DataTable/DataSet) pending this required db update.  I would also suggest that what you are trying to achieve here is not really the norm, so you might want to consider updating your original post with an explanation of why.

Comment: Might also be an idea to delete this question and ask a new question with a *Clear and Concise* explanation of exactly where you are, what you've attempted (In sorting what ever memory collection you have) and a *Clear and Concise* explanation of exactly why what you've attempted doesn't work.  You will find not many people will wade through the comments on this question to get to the bottom of what you're needing help with

Comment: You might also want to check in the help.  You can do things like tag users on your responses with a @ sign so they get notifications